# Subtract variables inside [ngStyle] angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I am making my `width` style property of my progressbar dynamic by subtracting variables `regOtValue` and `endTimeOverTimeOut` inside my [ngStyle] directive. but It always throws blank or an error of interpolating (by adding `{{ }}` inside the [ngStyle])

here is what I am doing:

```
 [ngStyle]="{'width': (getAttendance.regOtValue - getAttendance.attendance[getAttendance.findIndex].endTimeOverTimeOut) + '%', 'background-color': '#63B3EA'}"
```

please help me to get in track with my development.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `style=" width: {{ (getAttendance.regOtValue - getAttendance.attendance[getAttendance.findIndex].endTimeOverTimeOut) + '%;'  }} background-color : #63B3EA  "`

Comment: this method throws a warning : WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value width: -5.763888888888889%;; background-color : #63B3EA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning a value from a method like following:

Inside `.ts` file:

```
getWidth() {
 return (this.getAttendance.regOtValue - this.getAttendance.attendance[getAttendance.findIndex].endTimeOverTimeOut).toString() + '%';
}
```

And in your template:

```
 [ngStyle]="{'width':getWidth(), 'background-color': '#63B3EA'}"
```